# Objective-C Location to label text

Tags: objective-c, gps, location

I'm pretty new to objective c development.

I'm trying to get the longitude and latitude coordinates and assign the to labels.

However, when I load the app my labels don't update with the coordinates.

I'm sure that I am doing something very basic wrong but any help would be greatly appreciated!

.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface StartCycleViewController : UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *longitudeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latitudeLabel;
@property (nonatomic,strong) CLLocation *currentCycleLocation;
@property (nonatomic,strong) CLLocationManager *cycleLocation;

- (void) stopLocationManager;


@end
```

.m :

```
#import "StartCycleViewController.h"

@interface StartCycleViewController ()

@end

@implementation StartCycleViewController

@synthesize cycleLocation = _cycleLocation;
@synthesize currentCycleLocation = _currentCycleLocation;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self startCycleLocation];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - startCycleLocation

- (void)startCycleLocation{

    if (!_cycleLocation){
        _cycleLocation = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        _cycleLocation.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
        _cycleLocation.distanceFilter = 10;
        _cycleLocation.delegate = self;

    }
    [_cycleLocation startUpdatingLocation];

}

-(void) cycleLocation:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
         fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        self.longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",          currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        self.latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",   currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }

}


- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);

    if ( [error code] != kCLErrorLocationUnknown ){
        [self stopLocationManager];
    }
}

- (void) stopLocationManager {
    [self.cycleLocation stopUpdatingLocation];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have left this as a comment, but I don't have the reputation to do so.

What is going on in the line where you update the label?

```
self.longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",      c    currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
```

Why is that lone `c` there?

**EDIT:** So I realized this method

```
-(void) cycleLocation:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

was never getting called. After digging around I saw the method should be this instead:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

Replace the old signature with that one and it should work.

Comment: sorry, thats a mistype. The lone c isn't in the actual code.

Comment: Thanks mate, that was exactly the problem